# How to use Haskell cryptonite?

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I need Scrypt, AES256 and RSA from [cryptonite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite) and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to use them. Are there some good examples for these?

This [tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.21/docs/Crypto-Tutorial.html) is incomplete and it doesn't really count.

Thanks!

PS: I'm neither a cryptography nor a Haskell expert.

Comment: Hey nice that you have your try at haskell! But what is it you have tried where are you stuck? Right now I consider this question a bit too broad stackoverflow - can you narrow it down what you need?

Comment: OK. I'll remove this question and ask a more specific one. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to post a better question I managed to compile the code. I'm posting my solution hoping that it might help somebody else

```
import Crypto.Random(getSystemDRG, randomBytesGenerate)
import Crypto.KDF.Scrypt (generate, Parameters(..))
import Crypto.Cipher.AES (AES256)
import Crypto.Cipher.Types (BlockCipher(..), Cipher(..),nullIV)
import Crypto.Error (throwCryptoError)

saltSize = 32
paramN = 14 :: Word64
paramR = 8
paramP = 1
paramKeyLen = 32

-- AES256 encryption
encrypt :: ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString
encrypt key plainData = ctrCombine ctx nullIV plainData
  where ctx :: AES256
        ctx = throwCryptoError $ cipherInit key

decrypt :: ByteString -> ByteString -> ByteString
decrypt = encrypt

--Scrypt KDF
deriveKey :: Text -> ByteString -> ByteString
deriveKey password salt = generate params (encodeUtf8 password) salt
  where params = Parameters {n = paramN, r = paramR, p = paramP, outputLength = paramKeyLen}

-- for generating the salt
random :: Int -> IO ByteString
random size = do
  drg <- getSystemDRG
  let (bytes, _) = randomBytesGenerate size drg
  return bytes
```

Comment: "Trying to post a better question I managed to compile the code" I often find that's the case myself